# Blender: Having trouble moving vertices

Tags: blender

I've been using Blender for two days now, and ran into an issue while following a tutorial.

Before anything else, I'd like to show you all what my problem precisely is. Here is a short video I uploaded: [click here](http://flic.kr/p/d2ahEQ). I thought it may be easier for you all to help me identify and solve my problem more accurately with a visual aid.

I would like to emphasize that this issue began to occur after I extruded that trapezoidal region (misstated as a parallelogram in the video). I decided that I did not want the extruded region, and just hit undo. Ever since then, I began to experience the problem you viewed.

Thanks.

Comment: extrude seems to work as a 2-step process: a duplicate-and-connect verts, and then a move. I think You need to hit undo twice to fully reverse the extrude.

Comment: Agreed. Though, it's odd that there are vertices completely disconnected from any face. Some other weirdness going on as well, likely even more extra vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra vertices overlapping. You can merge them so you can get what you're expecting.

1. Switch to edit mode like you are in your video
2. Press `B` to go into box selection mode

   1. Ensure you have deselected "Limit Selection to Visible" or switch to wireframe mode
3. Draw a box around one of the four corners your having issues with (to select all the vertices there)
4. Press `Alt+M` to merge and select center
5. Repeat for each of the 4 corners
6. Observe that you now have 1 vertex per corner and they move like you expect.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I also had to deselect the "Limit Selection to Visible" option. I had earlier ran into a related problem where I deleted the face of that trapezoid shape, and was left with only the edges and vertices (I was able to see inside the model because it left a hole). If this question is not off topic, how would you suggest I fix that? I would need to fill the shape somehow. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're trying to fill a hole in a model, you can select the vertices surrounding the hole and create a new face. See my answer [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/fitting-a-cap-for-a-hollow-object-in-blender/21601#21601) for more details about that. Thanks for the feedback too, I usually work in wireframe mode, so I often forget about the limiting to visible option.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. I keep alternating between modes at the moment (as I am still learning).