# Blender: How to merge multiple meshes of same object?

Tags: blender, mesh

I have run into a bit of a problem creating my 3D model. I started with a single mesh and added additional meshes (all in edit mode) to create my geometric shape. They are all part of the same object, but now I can't figure out how to "carve" my desired shape of this geometric mesh pattern because some of my faces are going to get deleted etc.

Here are pictures of what I have, and what I want to achieve.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Goodness you have a lot of faces in those objects. Anyway, have you tried extruding your star shape and the performing a boolean operation on the two?

Comment: I wanted a smooth edge when I sculpt it later on (it is going to be a shuriken). The problem is, I can't extrude the faces because the meshes are overlapping, not joined. I don't know how to join them without destroying the perfect geometric shape. I tried "Removing Doubles" but that resulted in a disfigured mesh blob.

Comment: I suggest starting over. That's a crazy number of faces. Start with just the shuriken shape, and use the face tool to add faces to it. Something like [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/fitting-a-cap-for-a-hollow-object-in-blender).

Comment: One problem with doing it that way, how would I design it using precise geometry? I can't have a, "well that looks about right" model.

Comment: You might also want to try modelling a single spike and using array resp. wrap modifier to create the other spikes. If you really need to be precise, I'd recommend Robert Burke's precision modelling guide: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/r.burke2/precision_modelling1.html